# Dell p4 system not showing any display

Tags: desktop-computer

My Dell P4 Desktop system is not showing display and it smells like some things is burning. It has some small lights at right side of system that shows 1 2 3 4 and an oval shaped drum icon. They on some time, that box symbol then 1 3 on e.t.c.  It was working very well but after shifting home it all stopped showing display and there is a beep sound when we on it.

So what you guys suggest me? It was working very well and I was happy with this system.

Answer (score 2):

A burning smell is very bad sign. Most probable cause would be the power supply. Each Dell pc has a diagnostic or user manual you can download from Dell. Just enter your service code number on the support page to find the list of manuals available for that machine. In that manual, it will have a section troubleshooting power on problems. The number of beeps are a unique code that can be looked up there. (for example 3 short beeps might be bad memory). Also on the back of the PC, there are usually 4 diagnostic LEDs that display a boot code during startup. The meaning of the displayed code will be in your manual.
Good luck.